# Clicking parent selects child element's content

Tags: html, css

[image]

Clicking on parent elements(such as div with class `one` or body) but outside child element area makes child element's(div with class `two`) content to get selected/highlighted as shown in above image. How can I avoid that? Below is the link for codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyvVBr?editors=1100

```css
.one,
.two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
.two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.one .two {
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, red, blue);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, yellow);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that's expected behaviour and probably best not changed.

Comment: I didnt understand Do you want to higlight content or avoid to higlighted ?

Comment: Have u tried using javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following styles, using this the content won't be highlighted.

```
body {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}
```

You can also use Javascript:

```
element.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
}, false);
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, you can use the selector on body or element, according to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use user-select: none; (plus prefixes), but you should think carefully about potential side-effects in terms of accessibility etc.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Comment: Re Aakash answer, you would be best to add those rules to the closest relevent dom node (div class="two"), not the whole body - you would be blocked from selecting anything!